# Android: Most secure way to pass "The certificate of the peer does not match the expected hostname" error, for sockets?

Tags: java, android, websocket, ssl-certificate, wildcard

#### Summary:

How to create socket to a server with wildcard certificate when we get "The certificate of the peer does not match the expected hostname" error?

---

Basically, I want to create a secure websocket (wss) to a server with wildcard certificate. I'm using [this websocket library](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client). Now when I want to connect to the website the connection is instantly close with this error log:

> 2021-03-16 13:14:16.221 21027-21097/com.....app W/System.err: com.neovisionaries.ws.client.HostnameUnverifiedException: The certificate of the peer does not match the expected hostname (sthsth.sthsth.ir)
> 2021-03-16 13:14:16.221 21027-21097/com.....app W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.SocketConnector.verifyHostname(SocketConnector.java:281)
> 2021-03-16 13:14:16.222 21027-21097/com.....app W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.SocketConnector.doConnect(SocketConnector.java:246)
> 2021-03-16 13:14:16.222 21027-21097/com.....app W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.SocketConnector.connect(SocketConnector.java:190)
> 2021-03-16 13:14:16.222 21027-21097/com.....app W/System.err:     at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocket.connect(WebSocket.java:2351)
> 2021-03-16 13:14:16.223 21027-21097/com.....app W/System.err:     at com.....app.network.GeneralSocketService$1.run(GeneralSocketService.java:167)
>
> 2021-03-16 13:14:15.895 21027-21097/com.....app E/Conscrypt:
> ------------------Untrusted chain: ---------------------- 2021-03-16 13:14:15.896 21027-21097/com.....app E/Conscrypt: == Chain0 ==
> Version:   3 2021-03-16 13:14:15.897 21027-21097/com.....app E/Conscrypt:  Serial Number:   e63f80cf7a1220146cc8fd96d8468a4
> 2021-03-16 13:14:15.900 21027-21097/com.....app E/Conscrypt:
> SubjectDN:   CN=*.sthsthnet.ir, C=US 2021-03-16 13:14:15.908
> 21027-21097/com.....app E/Conscrypt:  IssuerDN:   CN=Certum Domain
> Validation CA SHA2, OU=Certum Certification Authority, O=Unizeto
> Technologies S.A., C=PL 2021-03-16 13:14:15.914
> 21027-21097/com.....app E/Conscrypt:  Get not before:   Tue Jul 30
> 10:35:53 GMT+04:30 2019 2021-03-16 13:14:15.916
> 21027-21097/com.....app E/Conscrypt:  Get not after:   Thu Jul 29
> 10:35:53 GMT+04:30 2021 2021-03-16 13:14:15.918
> 21027-21097/com.....app E/Conscrypt:  Sig ALG name:   SHA256withRSA
> 2021-03-16 13:14:15.921 21027-21097/com.....app E/Conscrypt:
> Signature:
> 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
> 2021-03-16 13:14:16.213 21027-21097/com.....app E/Conscrypt:  Public
> key:
>
> ```
>  30 82 01 22 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01 05 00 03
>  82 01 0f 00 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 9d b2 14 d0 11 c4 8f
>  29 42 7a ee 09 1e 30 2e 62 dd 14 b8 6b 7b 1b 6b fe 03 ba 6a
>  07 6b 6c 69 b3 07 58 51 cf c0 4c 67 15 7e 0f 46 45 33 2b f5
>  50 20 db 2c 45 f7 8a 52 29 d2 a0 10 65 31 1d 9f d9 90 2f 83
>  e9 d7 c1 ee 1a a6 e8 47 3d 89 fb 8b cf d0 d7 7f ac de d1 39
>  ec 4b 8d 43 a4 d5 c2 95 e4 ab 4e 6e 2b a6 b7 24 f7 62 1b 3e
>  4a 27 ca a0 d7 9f 22 c3 25 d8 bd 54 39 27 51 99 d5 fa 13 ed
>  88 8a 64 9c ce 60 38 ae ea 7e 5f ee ed b1 ff cf 30 56 6d 5c
>  01 ad 0c d8 87 f0 4f c7 89 85 e0 d1 08 89 e8 69 dc 6e 35 c0
>  7d fc e6 37 33 00 a9 c8 7b 88 9e eb 98 02 bc 6c 9c f4 b7 6b
>  87 ca 15 1d 31 37 95 07 8e d2 c8 6a db 92 e0 93 35 4b f8 b0
>  29 b9 8f 21 d8 70 0a 5d 91 c5 fb 9c 51 b2 3e a8 6e 53 78 64
>  5c e5 c3 06 02 ab e5 0e 11 96 ea a9 f4 99 ea f2 66 d2 c2 6b
>  86 eb 90 0d f1 85 3f ef 51 02 03 01 00 01
> ```

Now using I know using:

```
WebSocketFactory.setVerifyHostname(false);
```

results in another error and I do not want to alter my code so it verifies all kinds of certificates or self-signed certificates like this:

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
X509Certificate[] myTrustedAnchors = new X509Certificate[0];
return myTrustedAnchors;
}

@Override
public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
String authType) {
}

@Override
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
String authType) {
}
}};

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
factory.setSSLContext(sslContext);
socket = factory.createSocket(API_SOCKET);TooTallNate/Java-WebSockethttps://github.comTooTallNate/Java-WebSockethttps://github.com
```

Nor this:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
                    factory.setSSLContext(sslContext);
                    socket = factory.createSocket(API_SOCKET);
```

I also do not want to store server's certificate in my app because it may change time to time and the maintenance would get out of hand:

```
    //1. Get the cert file from the server 
    //2. Converted the cert to a BKS format
    
    
     // loading CAs from an InputStream 
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509"); 
InputStream cert = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_cert); 
Certificate ca;
 try {
 ca = cf.generateCertificate(cert);
 } finally {
 cert.close();
 } 
// creating a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs 
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType(); 
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType); 
keyStore.load(null, null); 
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca); 
// creating a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore 
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm(); 
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm); 
tmf.init(keyStore); 
// creating an SSLSocketFactory that uses our TrustManager 
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); 
sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

Is there another solution to pass only host verification issue without compromising security or maintanance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Wildcard certificates are trusted by Android devices, contrary to the custom certificates. There was no problem with the Android part of the code
The problem was that our backend guys had included only one of the certificate files on the code and not the certificate chain (the top certificate on the chain and not the other ones) that's why our `WebSocket` library produced that error.
Also in case of custom certificates, the best way is to certificate pinning or including server CA (Certificate Authority) files on the Android app and refer to it on manifest file but the app is prone to getting tampered with and needs security measures.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem before and found out, that certificates signed by big companies are trusted by devices, so when someone else tries to make their own certificate its very dangerous, because (in this case) android can not be sure, that your data is well-encrypted

You either should have the right certificate or trust them all. Second solution is okay for development, but should never be used in production